# Umbraco not updating models and controllers

Tags: razor, umbraco

New to Umbraco and having a problem updating the code of an existing site (Umbraco version 7.2.8).

Editing views works fine but when editing a model and/or controller the site does not change.

The files I'm editing are located in:

```
/Models/*.cs
/Controllers/*.cs
```

Could someone supply details on how to compile these?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Try to be more precise, and detail what you did. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added further details to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where your code behind files are located. If they're in /App_Code you shouldn't have to compile, I believe, but anything other than that (like /Models/*.cs or /Controllers/*.cs) will have to be compiled.

Comment: Could you please supply further information on compiling these files, I've updated the post to include additional details.

Comment: I'm using Atom, but have Visual Studio Code installed if that helps?

Comment: Maybe get Visual Studio Community (or Express) instead - otherwise you can google how to compile c# without Visual Studio :-/

Answer (score 0):

Your controller names should end with SurfaceController. 
All models you create as in Models folder. 
You might need to reference your models in controller